# Predefined QueryParsers

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

Where do find a comprehensive list of predefined QueryParser names for Solr (like "dismax" or "edismax") that I can use as `defType` in contexts like

`ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();

params.set("defType", "edismax");`

Where is this documented? How do I for example specify the standard Lucene query parser?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the [list of Query Parsers](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryParser).

The lucene is the default Query parser and you can use it by specifying `defType=lucene`